# Is There a Modern Gesture Solution On Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, kde, libinput

Multi-touch touchpads are the standard these days. I searched around for good support, ideally out of the box, on modern Ubuntu. To be more specific: I'm on Kubuntu 20.04 without any relevant PPAs.

Most solutions seem to involve [libinput-gestures](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures) which, to be honest, is a super hacky solution. It calls `libinput debug-events` under the hoods and reads its STDOUT. I'm happy to hear that this works for many people, but I would prefer to not have to use this.

I also found packages `xserver-xorg-input-multitouch` and `xserver-xorg-input-mtrack` but both of them have not been touched in many years and they seem to rely on synaptics, not the more modern libinput.

I wonder if someone knows of any modern (ideally KDE-based) solutions for getting swipes and pinches etc. to work. Or if there are any KDE tickets to follow that deal with this.

Comment: I tried to explain what I mean by "hacky" above: It calls another program which is meant to debug events, and parses it's STDOUT. See https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures/blob/master/libinput-gestures#L710 and below. I'd expect a "real" gesture manager to get the events from the device and not from another program. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hmm. I see what you're saying... I wonder if this is not done due to limitations of the touchpad driver itself? Could this implementation cause additional problems?  I'm asking just in case another method is not available. (I hope you can find one)

Comment: Just 3 days ago, the author of Touchégg started a new branch for libinput support: https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg/tree/feature/libinput – That's promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[touchegg](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg) now uses libinput since version 2.0.

As for KDE, I found this config file for touchegg and KDE that you might enjoy:
https://github.com/NayamAmarshe/ToucheggKDE

Here is an overview of this new version and of what would be needed for direct kde support:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o74_ddzi1kw